# Erro em WebService no Laravel 5.7

Tags: laravel, web-service

Estou tentando criar um `WebService` pelo `Laravel` usando o `symfony/process`, se eu rodar ele no command do windows ele preenche o log com sucesso (`php artisan gerar:arquivo 12 param1 1000`), mas quando tento rodar pela minha rota ele não preenche o log, ele me retorna o seguinte erro:

```
Symfony\Component\Process\Exception\ProcessFailedException: The command &quot;php artisan gerar:arquivo 12 param1 1000&quot; failed.

Exit Code: ()

Working directory: C:\xampp\htdocs\pw

Output:
================


Error Output:
================
 in file C:\xampp\htdocs\pw\app\Http\Controllers\PwController.php on line 339
Stack trace:
  1. Symfony\Component\Process\Exception\ProcessFailedException-&gt;() C:\xampp\htdocs\pw\app\Http\Controllers\PwController.php:339
  2. App\Http\Controllers\PwController-&gt;pw() C:\xampp\htdocs\pw\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Controller.php:54
  3. call_user_func_array() C:\xampp\htdocs\pw\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Controller.php:54
  4. Illuminate\Routing\Controller-&gt;callAction() C:\xampp\htdocs\pw\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\ControllerDispatcher.php:45
  5. Illuminate\Routing\ControllerDispatcher-&gt;dispatch() C:\xampp\htdocs\pw\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Route.php:212
```

Segue meu código:

```
<?php

namespace App\Console\Commands;

use Illuminate\Console\Command;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;

class Gerar extends Command
{

    protected $signature = 'gerar:arquivo {id} {param} {page_size}';
    protected $description = 'Aplicação para Gerar PDF';


    public function handle()
    {
        $page_size = $this->argument('page_size');
        $id = $this->argument('id');
        $param = $this->argument('param');

        Log::info($page_size);
        Log::info($id);
        Log::info($filtro);

    }

}
```

Note que eu estou gerando um `Log` com dados para teste mas não chega a preencher o log, parece que ele para no controller.

E o controller:

```
public function gerar(Request $request)
{
        $process = new Process(sprintf("php artisan gerar:arquivo %d %s %d", 1299, "param1", 1000), base_path());
        $process->start();
        //$process->wait();
}
```

Note tambem que se eu descomentar a linha `//$process->wait();` ele funciona, mas tenho que esperar o fim do processamento do `WebService` e não quero isso.

Comment: O $process->wait() fica em loop?

Comment: Da uma olhada nesses artigos

https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/running-artisan-command-through-symfony-process

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27022516/controlling-an-interactive-process-with-php-using-symfony-process

Answer (score 1):

De acordo com a documentação, [aqui está](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/artisan#programmatically-executing-commands) a maneira correta de chamar um comando em uma rota/controller, ex:

```
$exitCode = Artisan::call('email:send', [
    'user' => 1, '--queue' => 'default'
]);
```

Comment: Ele não quer isso, ele quer gerar logs com laravel